# In react: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am working on a web app using react-redux with a node.js backend. I was working on adding a page to add games to the profile. I am getting an error when running this code.

This is the action that it is using when I get the error

```
export const addGames = (gameData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/profile/games", gameData)
    .then(res => history.push("/dashboard"))
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
```

The page itself loads perfectly fine. only when the action is called does it error out. It points to the catch statement when it does error.

Making an API call through postman comes back as expected, and does not error.

the error I get is

```
×
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
eval
C:\dev\SocialNetworkTutorial\devConnector\client\src\actions\profileActions.js:48:14
  45 | axios
  46 |   .post("/api/profile", profileData)
  47 |   .then(res => history.push("/dashboard"))
> 48 |   .catch(err =>
     |            ^  49 |     dispatch({
  50 |       type: GET_ERRORS,
  51 |       payload: err.response.data
```

Comment: what is the actual error then?

Comment: edited post to include the error

Comment: Why do you expect `err` to have a `response` field? Try logging it out and seeing what's available. It's an Error object, so at a minimum it should have a `message` field

Comment: Try logging out the err object using JSON.stringify so that you can see the structure. The error seems to be suggesting that the structure is not what you are expecting (err.response.data). .catch(err => console.log(JSON.stringify(err)) )

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for responding. I figured it out. What I did was console log the err.message as advised and it gave me the error

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

This lead me to look at the history.push part of the code thinking history might not have gotten passed correctly.

I realized my main code for the onSubmit I had

```
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const gameData = {
      name: this.state.name,
      handle: this.state.handle,
      platform: this.state.platform,
      rank: this.state.rank
    };

    this.props.addGames(gameData, this.props.games);
  }
```

Then I realized that `this.props.addGames(gameData, this.props.games);` needed to be changed to `this.props.addGames(gameData, this.props.history);`

Answer (score 0):

Then problem is that axios's `err.response` object will only be present if the host **returns a response**, but is outside of the `2xx` status code range.

If the host errors out before returning a response or if there is an issue with your initial request then the `err.response` property won't exists and therefore `err.response.data` will throw an exception.

The most thorough way to handle errors would be something like this from [axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)...

```
.catch(function (error) {
  const errorMessage = (()=> {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
      return error.response.data;
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
      return error.request;
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
      return error.message;
    }
  })();

  dispatch({
    type: GET_ERRORS,
    payload: errorMessage
  })
});
```